# Form / ajax / PHP issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am trying to make a small form that lets the user pick one element from 3 different radiobutton lists to set one element as the users active element (that will be stored to MySQL). Somehow along the way it does not work and I can not seem to figure out why, perhaps someone of you can see what I did wrong?

HTML:

```
<form name="activeForm1" method="post">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <div class="ui-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="active" value="1" id="1">
        <label for="1"></label></input>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="active" value="2" id="2">
        <label for="2"></label></input>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="active" value="3" id="3">
        <label for="3"></label></input>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div data-role="footer">
    <input type="submit" href="#" onclick="setActive(1)"/>
</div>
</form>
```

JavaScript / Ajax call

```
function setActive(formid) 
    {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type:'POST',
                url:'active.php',
                data:$('#activeForm'+formid).serialize(),
                success:function(response)
                {
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

PHP code:

```
session_start();
include('connectToDb.php');
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

if (isset($_POST['active']))
{
    $formValue = $_POST['active'];
    mail('my@mail.com','Test',$formValue,'From: dummy@mail.com');
    mysql_query(/* UPDATE MySQL */);
    header("Location: main.php");
}
else
{
    mail('my@mail.com','Test','No data recieved!','From: dummy@mail.com');
}
```

So it works up until the `if (isset($_POST['active']))` but then mails me that no data was recieved. I already have 2 similar forms on the same page and they are way bigger and has no problems running. Can't figure out what I did wrong here.

Comment: Are you making sure that at least one of the radio buttons is checked before clicking the submit button?

Comment: Could you please add a `var_dump($_POST['active'])` ?

Comment: why href attribute to input element??

Comment: @asprin no. Dunno how to do it.. yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wrong code :**

```
  data:$('#activeForm'+formid).serialize(),
```

`#activeForm` is not an id, it is the name of the form tag,

**Correct the form tag to,**

```
<form name="activeForm1" id="activeForm1" method="post">
```

Comment: Damn..How did i miss that? Nice catch

Comment: Aaaaah! That makes perfect sense! Cheers! Been bugging me for hours now, can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 2):

Replace following line

```
data:$('#activeForm'+formid).serialize(),
```

with

```
data: $('form[name="activeForm'+formid+'"]').serialize(),
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<input type="submit" href="#" onclick="setActive(1)"/>
```

to

```
<input type="button" href="#" onclick="setActive(1)"/>
```

and then it should work